# JQuery Mobile - Listview - Round Image Thumbnails

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Anyone know how to make the thumbnails in JQuery Mobile's Listview widget completely round?  The images are uploaded as square images and I'd like to avoid re-processing them as round, server-side.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/mS7Cf/

Comment: @omar - Thanks, that seems to do the trick.  Should have known it's an easy solution.  If you place your comment in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm glad I've been of help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give images a class and override `border-radius` in addition to `border-top-left-radius` and `border-bottom-left-radius` which inherit their values from parent element.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/mS7Cf/)**

```css
.image {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px !important;
}
```